# Click through photo wall, with perspective

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemagick

So I'm building a portfolio and sales website for a painter (my wife) based on WooComerce (WordPress). This is a side project that I have plenty of time to finish. I want to build a live/moving photo wall, with perspective. The following photo will give you a (albeit, very rough) idea.

[image]

Basically, I want to start off with 16 images (the number is actually arbitrary), apply perspective to them and allow the visitor to click any of the pics and go to that images associated page. Now, after a given time, I want new photos to show up.

I'm not particularly concerned if I flip these pics, randomly, like tiles to introduce new ones OR if a column slides off and a new column is added (i.e. the adding of 17-20 in my picture). This is a semantic difference in the way I build this code and isn't part of my question (I don't think). All of the original pictures are going to be square and will be uploaded by the user, whom we assume is of novice/intermediate computer experience.

So my question is about the approach. Do I:

1. **Make my wall script (likely using jQuery and HTML < map > and < area >) take care of the flipping and linking, but the perspective and scaling is done and cached on the backend.**
   Every image I upload to the server, for the photo wall, run it through a ImageMagick script that will transform (i.e. apply perspective of the largest size for the wall) and then scale it down for the other columns using a naming convention like: orignalthumnail_marilyn.png perspective0_marilyn.png perspective1_marilyn.png etc. (with the number for the different columns, relating to the scaled sizes). This is will be harder on bandwidth (maybe not, if compressed correctly) and easiest on the user's hardware (assuming non-mobile).
2. **Use Javascript & CSS (and possibly HTML5) to do everything.** I load the images into  and use the CSS3 skewed/transformed < div >s, JS to flip/moves the tiles (I could do CSS I suppose). I feel that this option is the worst, as far as looks. This is because CSS clips horribly using the transform attribute (on my browser, FF 30) (I also made a quick demo at http://jsbin.com/febatohi/2/edit). Also, it requires the user's hardware to be able to handle *all* of the transforms, which is not always appreciated online. Maybe there is a way to handle this with a JS library I'm not aware of.
3. **Use Flash.** This is my least desirable option. It requires me to either not build this myself or pay someone else (pfft!) or that I acquire and learn Flash from Adobe (I said time wasn't an object, but patience can be). However, it can produce the best looking result, as I have seen things done similarly to this is Flash. It also is a middle ground of hardware and bandwidth, but to me the most time consuming and also limiting to those browsers and users who use Flash (though I feel this is only a small percentage of users).
4. **Other suggestions?**

Comment: number two if you have a lot of time and nothing to do!

Comment: @nol Well, it's not really a time thing, but an interest/patience thing. Also, like I said, to make it look decent with JS &| CSS, this is going to be intensive on user hardware. I found [perspective.js](https://code.google.com/p/html5rush/source/browse/trunk/perspective.js?spec=svn77&r=46) and have looked at demo's made with it, it could really make the image. Yet, I feel, this would be CPU intensive on 16 separate images for our average visitor.